# Force PHP to echo when loop finishes

Tags: php, hash, password-encryption, php-password-hash

I'm testing PHP5.5's new `password_hash` technique and, for debug purposes, am wanting to have PHP echo each time my `for` loop finishes, instead of waiting for the page to finish loading (or for apache to cut it). I am using wamp server for my debugging, and have enabled `implicit_flush`, and disabled `output_buffering`.

My code is:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    $wordtohash = "rasmuslerdorf";

    //require ircmaxell's PHP5 backward compat lib (https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)
    require 'lib/pw.php';

    echo "Beginning hashing: <br /><br /><hr /><br />";

    ob_flush();

    $options = [
        'cost' => 15
    ];

    for ($i=0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        if (isset($hashed)) {
            $wordtohash = $hashed;
        }

        //start counting
        $mtime = microtime();
        $mtime = explode(" ", $mtime);
        $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
        $start = $mtime;

        //hash
        $hashed = "Attempt {$i}: ".password_hash($wordtohash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);

        //end counting
        $mtime = microtime();
        $mtime = explode(" ",$mtime);
        $mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0];
        $end = $mtime;
        $totaltime = ($end - $start);
        echo $hashed." (total time: ".$totaltime." seconds)<br /><br />";

        ob_flush();
    }
?>
```

What this is doing is hashing a test word, "rasmuslerdorf", and collecting the hash and then sending that back in to be hashed (for as many times as the loop specifies).

I have a timer set up for each, but would like to have each show up on the page as they finish for testing.

I have tried using `ob_start()` followed by `ob_flush()` commands where needed, but that didn't work (`implicit_flush` is supposed to make it flush on `echo` or `print`, so I'm at a loss) and I have also tried `flush()`.

Does anyone happen to have any extra ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly are you rehashing 10 times?

Comment: @MarkBaker Testing speed, mostly. This is all a test.

Comment: Surely you should be hashing the original password 10 times to test speed, not rehashing 10 times, because you're changing the start value every iteration

Comment: your loop. You're hashing the hash value again and not 'rasmuslerdorf' anymore

Comment: And if you're just testing speed, it's always a lot easier to do from the command-line, not from a web page

Comment: I was doing that at first, but switched it up. I'll switch it back in a mo'. Anyway, do you know how to solve the problem with having it echo as page loads?

Comment: I'll try from command line as well, thanks.

Comment: @OraBrush , change `echo`to `var_dump` loop + echo concatinates all the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try using PHPs error_log() function:

```
$string = $hashed . " (total time: " . $totaltime . " seconds)" ;
error_log(print_r($string, true);
```

This will print your debug message to the PHP error log in real time without relying on the view layer of your application or interrupting the execution of your code. On a UNIX / Linux system or OS X you could tail the log. You could do this in windows too if you have Cygwin or another BASH emulator installed:

```
tail -f /path/to/your/error.log
```

You can use phpinfo() to determine the location of your PHP error log. If you have not specified custom settings for the log in your php.ini PHP will likely default to outputting errors to the Apache log.